# RxJs setTimeout for long running task with preventing a new interval until finish previous

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I found this docs for solving my problems:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#ensure_that_execution_duration_is_shorter_than_interval_frequency

```
(function loop(){
   setTimeout(function() {
      // Your logic here

      loop();
  }, delay);
})();
```

But how to rewrite this logic with help of RxJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this really depends on what "`// Your logic here`" is doing.

A faithful reading of that loop above might look like this:

```ts
const loop = new Subject();
loop.pipe(
  delay(1000) // delay 1 second
).subscribe(
  // Your logic here
  loop.next();
);
loop.next(); // Initiate the loop
```

This is rarely going to be the best solution as observables come with a lot of power and support to manage some otherwise very complex data-streams.

Comment: I think it should work. Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method is porbably this one:

```
const { interval } = require("rxjs");

const delay = 1000; // 1s

interval(delay).subscribe(() => {
  // Your logic here
});
```

However it would not wait for any asynchronous tasks to finish inside the subscription callback and it would run forever. But the are methods to handle asynchronous code or even to stop the interval. Just let me know if you need it (leave me a comment) I would add more code to my answer later.